# クラス AtomicBooleanについて。

Tags: java

以下のコードのようにAtomicBooleanというクラスがありますがこれは「Boolean flg = true;」というものとどう違い、どう使い分けるのでしょうか。

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicBoolean flg =new AtomicBoolean();
flg.set(true);
System.out.println(count.get());
System.out.println(flg.get());
```

Comment: [これ](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/java-rules/vna02-j.html)を読むといいかも。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単に言えば `AtomicBoolean`＝「複数スレッドから安全に同時アクセスできる`boolean`型」です。質問中コードのように単一スレッドからしかアクセスしない場合には、ソースコード記述が面倒になるだけで、全くメリットがありません。

スレッドセーフの観点から、3種類の選択肢があります：

- `boolean`型：複数スレッドから安全に同時アクセスすることはできません。マルチスレッド処理中から安全にアクセスするには`synchronized`文などで排他制御が必要です。`Boolean`クラスは、このプリミティブ型`boolean`に対応します。
- `volatile boolean`型：**単純な代入と値の読取りに限定して**、複数スレッドから安全にアクセスできます。（念のため; この性質はJava 5以降でのみ保証されます。）
- `AtomicBoolean`クラス：提供されるインスタンスメソッドを通して、単純代入(`set`)や値の読取り(`get`)のほか、"値比較してから更新(`compareAndSet`)"といった処理を複数スレッドから安全に行えます。

---

[Javaリファレンスマニュアル](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) にも説明があります。

> 原子的な更新が可能な`boolean`値です。原子変数のプロパティの詳細は、`java.util.concurrent.atomic`パッケージ仕様を参照してください。`AtomicBoolean`は、原子的に更新されるフラグなどのアプリケーションで使用されます。これを`Boolean`の代替として使用することはできません。

Answer (score 1):

スレッドセーフであるかどうかに違いがあります。マルチスレッドでの動作を考慮する必要があれば、`AtomicBoolean`を使います。